# mariaDB 10.1.44-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 : how to change the blank root password?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I tried MANY things:
like:

```
 use mysql;
 update user SET PASSWORD=PASSWORD("password") WHERE USER='root';
 flush privileges;
```

or

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

or

```
mysqladmin -u root -p password newpass
```

Then flush privileges, restart mysql

**and root password is still BLANK**: I can login to mysql with a simple

```
mysql
```

with no password

(and of course I cannot login to phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Debian 9 the default authentication (when connecting via a unix socket/localhost) is done via the unix socket authentication plugin:

"The unix_socket authentication plugin works by calling the getsockopt system call with the SO_PEERCRED socket option, which allows it to retrieve the uid of the process that is connected to the socket. It is then able to get the user name associated with that uid. Once it has the user name, it will authenticate the connecting user as the MariaDB account that has the same user name."

So changing the password will of course not work, unless you disable the plugin.
See also [Authentication Plugin - Unix Socket](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/)

Comment: Just to add to this, it seems that on a default installation MariaDB add root user grants for both mysql_native_password and unix_socket logins when you run the `mysql_secure_installation` command. So if disabling the plugin isn't an option you can remove the unix_socket grant from the root user account and that will stop root being able to log-in without a password.